# How to work with unit cells in Vesta

Tags: vesta

I am really confused about why whenever I add one molecule into vesta, around 6 show up randomly not at that position? What's the correct procedure for working unit cells?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, it turned out I was using a CIF file, transforming and then using structural parameters to add atoms, converting to .vasp fixed all the issues!

More detailed answer, I was using a CIF unit cell file, which is fairly normal, and then transformed it to a supercell, and was trying to add molecules using "Edit Data > Structural Parameters", however the issue with this was that by editing a CIF file, there was some issue, so exporting the supercell into .vasp, and then re-opening it and using edit data, it worked much better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).